# Ruby: How to get indexes for an array from another array in specific order?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing

how can I get the indexes for an array from another array in specific order? Not sure if I describe it correctly, please review the expected result below.

```
first_array = ["a1","a2","c1","c2","b1","a1","a2","a3"]
second_array = ["a1","a2","a3"]

def get_indexes(first_array, second_array)
   ...(do something)...
end

expected output: [5,6,7]
```

I have been trying out with different method like `find_index()` but it returns output `[0,1,7]` which is not the output I want, because I am looking for the **indexes where** `["a1", "a2", "a3"]` **are aligned**, from the `first_array` where `["a1", "a2", "a3"]` aligned is at **index 5, 6, and 7**.

Comment: Why is `[5,6,7]` correct but `[0,1,7]` is not? What are the rules?

Comment: There is no similarity I found on array please explain test cases in detail.

Comment: Please explain what are the acceptance rules for your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Array#rindex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-rindex):

```
['a', 'c', 'c'].rindex('c') # 2
```

This returns the index of the last element instead of the first.

```
def get_sequential_indexes(first_array, second_array)
  first_array.map { |e| second_array.rindex(e) } 
end

get_sequential_indexes(
  ["a1","a2","c1","c2","b1","a1","a2","a3"],
  ["a1","a2","a3"]
) # 5,6,7
```

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the output, you are returning the index of the first instance of `second_array[i]` in `first_array`, but I think you are wanting this only if the indexes are sequential. The following method do that:

```
def get_sequential_indexes(first_array, second_array)
  length_of_second = second_array.length
  first_array.each_with_index do |_, i|
    end_index = length_of_second + i - 1
    if arr_one[i..end_index] == second_array
      return (i..end_index).map(&:itself)
    end
  end
end

[1] pry(main)> get_sequential_indexes(first_array, second_array)
=> [5, 6, 7]
```

This will return the indexes of the first instance of the values of `second_array` appearing sequentially in `first_array`.

Could be more idiomatic ways to get there, but its a start for you!